# How to pass multiple variable and auto redirect to another php file?

Tags: php

If want to pass multiple variables in save.php

```
header('Location: save.php?id_no='.$id_no.'?f_name='.$f_name.'?l_name='.$l_name.);
```

Comment: put in cookies and access them in next page..if not logged in
if after logged in then use Sessions

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
header('Location: save.php?id_no='.$id_no.'?f_name='.$f_name.'?l_name='.$l_name.);
```

to

```
header('Location: save.php?id_no='.$id_no.'&f_name='.$f_name.'&l_name='.$l_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have extra `.` dot at last
2. Also using multiple `?` question mark is wrong use `&` ampersand
3. Use `"` instead of `'` to process php variable which do not need `.` dots to concatenate

Simply try like this

```
header("Location: save.php?id_no=$id_no&f_name=$f_name&l_name=$l_name");
```