# How to pass multiple variables in a href?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I tried some code based on similar questions but keep getting error. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384138/passing-multiple-variables-in-a-href-using-php-and-get) similar question I tried:

```
$step1 = 'my_shop';
$step2 = 'https://my-website.com/';
echo '<a href="' .$step2. .$step1. '">';
```

Following the logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478401/how-to-pass-multiple-variable-and-auto-redirect-to-another-php-file) similar question I also tried:

```
$step1 = 'my_shop';
$step2 = 'https://my-website.com/';
echo '<a href="' .$step2&$step1. '">';
```

Comment: Use `?` symbol at begging, like this: `echo '<a href="' .$step2. '?' .$step1. '=' . $step1_value . '">';` Any next parameter will use `&` as a concatenation

Comment: Also take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: Look into routes with changes on .htccess ..... the route need not be a sub folder for `my_shop` as you have if you manipulate the .htacess ... Your PHP script can then (at index.php for example) can then parse the URL for the page

Comment: You need to understand the basic structure of a [URL and query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL) for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `http_build_query()` function, as it was designed for this:

```
$data = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'boom',
    'cow' => 'milk',
    'php' => 'hypertext processor'
);
```

and then:

```
$base_url = 'https://my-website.com/';
$query_params = http_build_query($data);
$link = $base_url . '?' . $query_params;

echo '<a href = "' . $link . '">link text</a>';
```

Result:

```
<a href = "https://my-website.com/?foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor">link text</a>
```